# FCM push notification not working when app is closed Android

Tags: java, php, android, curl, push-notification

Ok so i have looked everywhere and I can't find an answer to this.
I have implemented the push notification in my Android app and everything works fine while the app is alive (Foreground or background), however if I close the app I stop receiving notifications.
Here is the php code where I send the notification.

```
public static function sendNotification($token){
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'notification' => array("title" => "Test","body" => "Test Message","icon" => "default","sound" => "default"),
        "data" => "test message",
        'to' => $token
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyAKHM3MoMACjmeVK46TDg8-rTj1KoVjzWs',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);                           
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === FALSE) {
        throw new errorSendingNotification();
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    // Result returns this
    // {"multicast_id":8978533958735781479,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1468627796530714%7c0e4bee7c0e4bee"}]}
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: do you have a service for notifications in your app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Comment: I am also facing problem with FCM, may I know please after getting the response like u mentioned in comment line, what to do with that response

Comment: I am not creating any backend server for my app, just calling the api in my MainActivity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. And this helped me.

Please remove "notification" key from payload and provide only "data" key.

Application handles notification messages only if the app is in foreground but it handles data messages even if the application is in background or closed.

If the application is in the foreground onMessageReceived handle both *data* and *notification* messages. If the application is closed or in the background only *data* messages are delivered to onMessageReceived . *notification* messages are not delivered to onMessageReceived . So you can't customize your messages.

It would be better to remove *notification* key from payload.

Comment: In this situation, you can override handleIntent in FirebaseMessagingService.
when app is closed, this method will fire

Comment: I found that when the `notification` key is removed, the push notification stops working on iOS when the app is killed. Does anyone encounter this?

Comment: @MajidSadeghi this works for me
i close app now i can see logs

Answer (score 1):

> One Solution is as AmAnDroid Gave.
>
> 2nd solution is:
>   Unfortunately this was a limitation of Firebase Notifications in SDK 9.0.0-9.6.1. When the app is in the background the launcher icon is use from the manifest (with the requisite Android tinting) for messages sent from the console.
>
> With SDK 9.8.0 however, you can override the default! In your AndroidManifest.xml you can set the following fields to customise the icon and color:
>
> Add below code in menifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/com_facebook_button_send_icon_blue" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/bt_blue_pressed" />
```

> Body/Payload:

```
{ "notification": 
 {
   "title": "Your Title",
   "text": "Your Text",
   "click_action": "MAIN_ACTIVITY" // should match to your intent filter
 },
 "data": 
 {
   "keyname": "any value " //you can get this data as extras in your activity and this data is optional
 },
 "to" : "to_id(firebase refreshedToken)"
}
```

> After with this add below code(intent-filter) in your acivity to be called:

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MAIN_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

> Make sure your Body/Payload's "click_action": "MAIN_ACTIVITY" and intent-filter's android:name="MAIN_ACTIVITY" should match.

Comment: What exactly your issue is? @AjayPandya

Comment: Let me try another way which i found rightnow on one blog of ravitamada otherwise i'll let you know here in detail or show you code if required